# relative include_path in WAMP installation

Tags: php, wamp

I just installed WAMP on my new computer, and have set everything up so that localhost and my alias website works.

I am having trouble setting up the include_path. It was set up to `.;C:\php\pear` and I changed it to `/`. This left me with these error messages:

```
 Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'MYFILENAME.php' for inclusion (include_path='/') in C:\wamp\www\MYSITENAME\index2.php on line 13
```

I've made sure that `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` are both enabled.

Does anyone know what I should change or what more setup needs to be done so that my `include("somefile.php")` will work properly?

Also, what additional information would you need to help troubleshoot this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Environment variables and PATHs if set via Windows use the C:\ format

Comment: / isn't the right slash for starters. The include_path is a list of locations separated by a semicolon, i.e. ".;c:\php\includes". The locations must reside under your web root, wherever that may be. The period literally means "the current directory". The locations are searched in the order given. I'm guessing that your include_path would be something like ".;c:\wamp\www\MYSITENAME\includes\".

Comment: Also, read up on Windows paths and read the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: @IanAtkin Thank you!!! why not submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

/ isn't the right slash for starters. The include_path is a list of locations separated by a semicolon, i.e. ".;c:\php\includes". The locations must reside under your web root, wherever that may be. The period literally means "the current directory". The locations are searched in the order given. I'm guessing that your include_path would be something like ".;c:\wamp\www\MYSITENAME\includes\".

Also, read up on Windows paths and read the PHP manual: php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path.